# Parse.com: Filter by dates (between) via REST API

Tags: rest, parse-platform

In one of my Parse classes there's a Date column, call it sentDate, that stores the date something was sent. Through the REST API I've been unable to query records where the sentDate falls between two dates. Example:

where={"sentDate":{"$gt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-03-03T14:53:25.000Z"}},"sentDate":{"$lt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-03-06T14:53:25.000Z"}}}

What I've observed is that the first date filter essentially gets ignored. In the example above, the "gt" is ignored, and all records with sentDate "lt" 2015-03-06T14:53:25.000Z are returned.

Is this not possible through the REST API or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all queries of column following.

Like so

```
where={"sentDate":{"$gt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-03-03T14:53:25.000Z"},"$lt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2015-03-06T14:53:25.000Z"}}}
```

You can see an sample in the doc : https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#container17